Does gradle kotlin buildSrc support defining dependent modules in this format implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":myModule")))
I am currently migrating my android project to employ buildSrc for its gradle kts configuration.
I am stuck with the following types of dependency declarations in their original form as i can not see how to convert them to buildSrc approach
  implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":myModule")))

will i have to create an extension function on org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler to support the mapOf approach?
I prefer mapOf to this to
Will this be the same for
implementation(files("libs/mylib-debug.aar"))
